# Overloading subscript operator for non-array elements

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have written a templates class for storing multiple bools in an integer.
Right now, setting and getting each bool is done with explicit functions

```
    bool isBitSet(int index)
    {
        return static_cast<bool>((block_ >> index) % 2)
    }

    void setBitOn(int index)
    {
        block_ |= 1 << index;
    }
```

I believe that the following would work for getting a value, but how would setting work since we can't directly return a reference for a bit?

```
    const bool operator [] (int index) const 
    {
        return static_cast<bool>((block_ >> index) % 2);
    }
```

Comment: And all other uses of the subscript operator goes kaboom!

Comment: It's not a good idea to overload an operator for something else that the regular types do.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `std::bitset` instead of making one?

Comment: @Rapptz - This is all inside a class, so shouldn't there be no affect when [] is called by something of a different class?

Comment: Return something that is not a reference to a bit but behaves like one (has a conversion to `bool` and an overloaded assignment that does the right thing).

Comment: @chris - simply because the implementation interested me and it turned out not to be too difficult to do. So basically, as an exercise.

Comment: @chewsocks I meant as a general practice. It's not a good idea to overload `operator[]` to do something else other than what it actually does (accessing an array element). If you want to do something else you can do `operator()` instead. This is talked about in Effective C++, I believe.

Comment: @Rapptz Do you avoid using `std::vector`, then, too? The class in this question is just as array-like as that.

Comment: @Rapptz - OK, I see. Is the implementation exactly the same, besides changing the brackets to parentheses?

Comment: @hvd yeah I *hate* std::vector. And yes chewsocks, it's exactly the same except changing the brackets to parentheses.

Comment: @n.m. - I agree that would be the way to go, but I don't know howto link accessing operator and the assignment operator.

Comment: @hvd - How did you come to the conclusion that Rapptz does not like `std::vector`?

Comment: @chewsocks `std::vector` provides `operator[]` with the same meaning as the class in this question. It doesn't *actually* return an array element, but it behaves close enough to it for `operator[]` to be the most sensible operator to use.

Comment: `std::vector::operator[]` returns a reference to the element specified.

Comment: I'm trying to read through the `stl_vector.h` source, but I'm admittedly not following it too well.

Comment: *your class accessing operator* returns an object of another class that overloads *an assignment operator of that other class*. That's the link.

Comment: @Rapptz Firstly, that's not what you said. You said `operator[]` should access an array element. Secondly, `std::vector<bool>::operator[]` doesn't return a reference to `bool`, it returns a special helper class exactly like what you oppose here.

Comment: @hvd I'm sick of discussing with you and it seems you failed to understand what I meant or I have failed at interpreting it properly and in plain English, so instead I will [kindly point you to what I meant in a longer manner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421708/1381108).

Comment: @Rapptz See Csq's answer, as far as the user is concerned, it *does* behave like an array of `bool`s (and it was clear from the question that it would), so I don't see any problem with using `operator[]` for it. Your longer explanation says the same thing, reversed, roughly: don't use `operator[]` if it doesn't act like the built-in `[]` operator. That doesn't apply here. So what is your problem, exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same is done in `std::vector<bool>` and in `std::bitset` in the standard library. As stated in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), `std::vector<bool>` it returns a proxy class that has its operators overloaded to act as an element of the vector.

You could to that as well.

For a user-friendly example see again the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) for a public interface, it is something like this:

```
template <class Allocator>
class vector<bool, Allocator> {
  // ...
  public:
    class reference {
        friend class vector;
        reference();
      public:
        ~reference();
        operator bool() const;
        reference& operator=(bool x);
        reference& operator=(const reference&);
        void flip();
    };
  // ...
};
```

To implement this class you should store a member pointer to your actual data block and a mask to operate with.

For a real example, in the g++ headers look for member class of `std::vector<bool>` called `std::vector<bool>::_Bit_reference` in the file `bits/stl_bvector.h`.

---

To clarify the OP with an example:

Let's say you have a class containing 320 bools. You could write it as:

```
class boolcontainer {
  uint32_t data[10];
public:
  //default ctor. to initialize the elements with zeros
  boolcontainer() { for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { data[i] = 0; } }
}
```

You want to add an operator[]. To add a const one is easy:

```
class boolcontainer {
  uint32_t data[10];
public:
  bool operator[](int i) const { return data[i/32] & (1 << (i%32)); }
}
```

to have a non-const one you need much more. First you need to create a class that represents a reference to your value. You must have some kind of pointer to where the value is stored and (in this case) you need a bitmask to specify one concrete bit. To be able to handle this as a bool& you need to add some operators, namely conversion to bool and operator=:

```
class reference {
  uint32_t *dataptr;
  uint32_t mask;
public:
  //constructor just initializing members
  reference(uint32_t *dataptr_, uint32_t mask_) : dataptr(dataptr_), mask(mask_) {}

  //conversion to bool
  operator bool() const {
    //just like in the getter, but the bitmask is stored now locally
    return *dataptr & mask;
  }

  //sets one single bit represented by mask to b
  reference& operator=(bool b) {
    if (b) {
      *dataptr |= mask;
    } else {
      *dataptr &= ~mask;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  //TODO copy ctor., operator==, operator<
};
```

Note that the above struct will behave as a bool& -- reading from it reads the value from the data point represented by the pointer and the mask, and similarly, writing to it overwrites the bit at the represented location. I also wrote a constructor that initializes the members.

Now all you need is that your boolcontainer's operator[] should return an object of the above class:

```
class boolcontainer {
  uint32_t data[10];
public:

  boolcontainer() { for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { data[i] = 0; } }

  class reference {
     ... //see above
  }

  //keep the const version for efficiency
  bool operator[](int i) const { return data[i/32] & (1 << (i%32)); }

  //non-const version returns our reference object.
  reference operator[](int i) { return reference(&data[i/32], 1 << (i%32)); }
};
```

And now some code to test it (prints only the first 40 values):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boolcontainer.h"

void printboolcontainer(const boolcontainer &bc)
{
    //note that this is the constant version
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
        std::cout << bc[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boolcontainer bc;
    printboolcontainer(bc);
    bc[0] = true;
    bc[3] = true;
    bc[39] = true;
    printboolcontainer(bc);
}
```

Comment: I've been looking at it and I got as far as `_Bit_reference operator[](ptrdiff_t __i) const {return *(*this + __i);}` but can you help me understand what that is doing?

Comment: added example to clarify. STL does the same spiced with templates and underscored identifiers.

Comment: Thanks! That I was mostly able to follow..but question still. Why do you return `*this` from `reference operator=(int i)`?

Comment: This is a really great answer.