# How to write non-const getter functions for classes with proxy reference?

Tags: c++, wrapper, proxy-classes, boost-dynamic-bitset

In particular I am trying to create some wrapper functions around boost::dynamic_bitset. There is a similar question, [Overloading subscript operator for non-array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807210/overloading-subscript-operator-for-non-array-elements) although I'm hoping for a more compact solution without creating additional classes. The relevant snippet:

```
typdef boost::dynamic_bitset<> BitWorld;
class Game{
    struct Grid{
        int size;
        BitWorld world;
    } grid;
public:
    BitWorld::reference& operator()(int x, int y) { return grid.world[x+y*grid.size]; }
    BitWorld::reference& operator[](int index) { return grid.world[index]; }
}
```

With MSVC13_64 this doesn't give me any errors, although it produces very strange behaviour when put to the test, with MinGW492_32 I get errors like this:

> C:\repositories\..\logic\game_prim.h:78: error: invalid
>   initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'boost::dynamic_bitset<>::reference&' from an rvalue of type
>   'boost::dynamic_bitset<>::reference'
>        BitWorld::reference& operator[](int index) { return grid.world[index]; }
>                                                                            ^

I don't see why they made working with mutating operations on proxy references so non-trivial. Simple casting won't work either, const_cast cannot convert between rvalue and lvalue refs and I didn't achieve much success with static_cast either.

Comment: They I'd be trying to assign to rvalue references, or wait..

Comment: Yes it works flawlessly, as well as with std::vector<bool>::reference. I had the wrong idea of what a proxy reference is, it really is a reference; and the other answer confused me a bit. Thanks.